# Match row value in a column with other column's name in BIGQUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In bigquery, is there a way to make 'L' operation? Say where:

```
  +----------------+---------------+----------------+
  |     COL1       |      COL2     | FOO            |
  +----------------+---------------+----------------+
  | identif11      |   BAR         |     VALUE1     | 
  | identif22      |    FOO        |     VALUE2     | 
  +----------------+---------------+----------------+
```

if value in (COL2) matches (FOO) return value in (FOO), and maybe add it to new column.

I am a rookie in SQL, I could do this in python but I'm dealing with datasets of millions of rows and i need something more powerful here

L-operator(COL1, FOO) should return VALUE2 in the second row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> Option 1

```
#standardSQL
SELECT col1, col2, foo, bar, 
  CASE col2 
    WHEN 'BAR' THEN bar
    WHEN 'FOO' THEN foo
  END L
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'identif11' col1, 'BAR' col2, 'VALUE1' foo, 'VALUE3' bar UNION ALL
  SELECT 'identif22', 'FOO', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE4'
)
SELECT col1, col2, foo, bar, 
  CASE col2 
    WHEN 'BAR' THEN bar
    WHEN 'FOO' THEN foo
  END L
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with result

```
Row col1        col2    foo     bar     L    
1   identif11   BAR     VALUE1  VALUE3  VALUE3   
2   identif22   FOO     VALUE2  VALUE4  VALUE2
```

> Option 2

You can "refactor" above a little - by using SQL UDF as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION L(val STRING, t ANY TYPE) AS (
  CASE val 
    WHEN 'BAR' THEN t.bar
    WHEN 'FOO' THEN t.foo
  END  
);
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'identif11' col1, 'BAR' col2, 'VALUE1' foo, 'VALUE3' bar UNION ALL
  SELECT 'identif22', 'FOO', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE4' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'identif22', 'AAA', 'VALUE2', 'VALUE4'
)
SELECT col1, col2, foo, bar, L(col2, t) L
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

with result

```
Row col1        col2    foo     bar     L    
1   identif11   BAR     VALUE1  VALUE3  VALUE3   
2   identif22   FOO     VALUE2  VALUE4  VALUE2   
3   identif22   AAA     VALUE2  VALUE4  null
```

> Option 3

And, finally, version that does not require knowing in advance and referencing in code explicitly columns' names

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION L(val STRING, t ANY TYPE) AS (
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(
    TO_JSON_STRING(t),
    CONCAT(r'(?i)"', val, '":"?([^"}]+)"?')
  ) 
);
SELECT col1, col2, foo, bar, L(col2, t) L
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

Note: 3rd option is not fully tested and might have some edge cases - but for simple cases like in your sample data  - should work well